# Validate XML Element for Mandatory value

Tags: asp.net, xml, validation, xsd

I want to create an *XSD* for an *XML*. I have XML elements declared with the `xs:string` data type where that data is mandatory. I created an XSD and set `minOccurs="1"`, but then found out that its purpose is to just check whether the element appears in the XML. I also discovered that there is a keyword `use="required"` but it is for attributes and cannot be used in the XML element. I finally tried `nillable="false"` but the XSD was validated without any data in my element.

This is my document:

```
<HelloWorld>
  <Name></Name>
  <Gender></Gender>
</HelloWorld>
```

And XSD:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="HelloWorld">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Name" minOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:int" name="Gender"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Here I want the data in the `Name` element to always be present (it's a mandatory field). When I validate this file it will throw an error for `Gender` saying that it contains an invalid integer. If you put some numbers it will start validating successfully but it won't check the data inside the `Name` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It validates because an empty string *is* a valid `xs:string`. `Gender` fails when empty because an empty string *is not* a valid `xs:int`.

If you want to force `Name` validation to fail when empty, you have to add a *restriction*. You choose what kind of restriction you need: a minimum string length, certain string characters (an enumeration or a pattern), etc. In the example below, I added a restriction which requires that the string be at least one character long:

```
<xs:element name="Name" minOccurs="1">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Now it will fail if `Name` is empty.